# how can I replicate the Apple Store App's top navigation bar?

Tags: ios, swift, navigationbar

The "Apple Store" app (*not* the app store) has a navigation bar at the top. It is transparent, scrollable (left, right) and dismisses when page content is scrolled down and reappears when scrolling up. Would you know what type of view controllers I could replicate this with? I am trying to understand if I could use some *out-of-the-box* functionality or if I need to implement this completely on my own (with a table view perhaps?)

Thank you very much

[image]

Comment: This [Apple sample](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/NavBar/Introduction/Intro.html) might give you some ideas on how to do it

Comment: thank you Leonardo, this seems to be the right approach